# RESTful Webservice does not handle Request Method properly

Tags: java, rest, request, jax-rs

I am retreiving values from multiple RESTful Web Service methods.
In this case two methods interfere with one another, due to a problem with the Request Method.

```
@GET
@Path("/person/{name}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Person getPerson(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("@GET /person/" + name);
    return people.byName(name);
}

@POST
@Path("/person")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void createPerson(Person person) {
    System.out.println("@POST /person");
    System.out.println(person.getId() + ": " + person.getName());
    people.add(person);
}
```

As I try to call the createPerson() method using the following code, my Glassfish Server will result in "@GET /person/ **the name I'm trying to create a person on**". Which means the @GET method is called, even though I did not send a {name} parameter (as you can see in the code).

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/service/person");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
marshaller.marshal(person, connection.getOutputStream());
```

I know this is asking a lot of digging in my code, but what am I doing wrong in this case?

**UPDATE**

Because createPerson is a void, I do not handle a connection.getInputStream().
This actually seems to result in the request not being handled by my Service.

But the actual request is sent on the connection.getOutputStream(), right?

**UPDATE 2**

The RequestMethod does work, as long as I handle a method with a return value and thus connection.getOutputStream(). When I try calling a void and thus not handling connection.getOutputStream(), the Service will not receive any request.

Comment: what if using cURL? `curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/service/person`

Comment: Try removing the accept header from your request

Comment: m not sure on this. trying to help u debug. we need to figure out why GET is being called.So does the sequence matters? might be that GET is first match for "/person" url pattern

Comment: I think that methods annotated with JAX-RS annotations have to return something. Try replacing the void return type with string and returning just anything.

Comment: I can confirm that removing the accept header does NOT make a difference.

Comment: @Raffaele I'm not sure how to execute that command (pretty basic stuff, I know)?

Comment: @Tom I can confirm that this will result in the same issue and thus can not be the solution. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: well, u need to have curl first. google it, set it up. also u need to write down the headers as well. not sure but it might look like this: curl -X POST -h "accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/service/person -v

Comment: @Aquillo curl is a command line utility to test if the problem is on the client or on the server side. On Linux it's commonly available

Comment: @Aquillo as an alternative to curl, you can use rest-client. It's a very simple and easy to use java application that allows you to test RESTful services http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll give it a try right away!

Comment: I can at least confirm that a @DELETE does work:
@.GET @.Path("/person/{name}") getPerson
@.DELETE @.Path("/person/{name}") deletePerson

Comment: POST with URL http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/service/person and BODY <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><person><id>51</id><name>POJO</name></person> gives a HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: You probably shouldn't return `void` from that POST handler; a `Response` would be better (and could redirect to the GET handler, a known REST pattern).

Comment: How can I handle this redirect? Simply by putting getPerson(person.getName()) into my createPerson() method?

Answer (score 3):

You should set the "Content-Type" instead of "Accept" header. Content-Type specifies the media type sent to the recipient, while Accept is about the media type accepted by the client. More details on headers are [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Here is the Java client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><person><name>1234567</name></person>";
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/service/person");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);        

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    wr.close();
    rd.close();

    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Here is the same using curl:

```
curl -X POST -d @person --header "Content-Type:application/xml" http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/service/person
```

, where "person" is a file containing the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><person><name>1234567</name></person>
```

Comment: Or you can also add 
@Produces("application/xml") 
@Consumes("application/xml")
to both methods and give it a try again. I think in this case it needs to run as well.

Comment: A HTTP connection has a request and response, so I you need to read the response. As well, it would be good that a method will return some sort of status about its success and then reading the response will make more sense.