# Making a REST call

Tags: web-services, rest, web-applications, struts2

I am using Struts-2 framework to design a web interface. API is already implemented in scala and play framework.
Is there a way HttpURLConnection or HttpClient can be used to make REST call in jsp? 
If yes can someone give me an example? Any reference of any book or site would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example on a main method, but jsp should be similar: [RESTful Webservice does not handle Request Method properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903073/restful-webservice-does-not-handle-request-method-properly/10907075#10907075). But, I'm not sure I understand why you can't just post/get using a form?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to Web programming.Could you give an example of post/get in a form? Do you mean method call to REST API should be done using get/post?

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on struts: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-stextfield-textbox-example/. It shows how to create a simple for sending page. Notice the "namespace" and "action" that need to map over the rest api interface that you expose.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, in this example it seems that local REST interface will be accessed. I will be accessing REST api interface which will be remote. So, how could I access that service?